# Plone 4 newbie can't create a web site - no username/password

Tags: passwords, plone, credentials

I am a new Plone user. I have installed Plone from docker image eeacms/plone:4.3.7. But I can't create a web site because I have no username/password.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this Docker image. But the standard that I expect is: username admin and password admin.

When I look at the config in https://hub.docker.com/r/eeacms/plone/ this seems to be correct.  See the 'user' option in the 'plone.recipe.zope2instance' recipe on that page.

Note that this username and password in the config file is only used once when there is no initial user yet.  When you have started the site at least once, changing the user option will have no effect anymore.  You can change the password later in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the next instructions

`cd data1/parts/zope2/utilities/`

data1/parts/zope2/utilities/ is a path to utilities folder, that contains zpasswd.py script Note: data1 is not the default name of folder in a plone/zope installtion, find zpasswd.py

`./zpasswd.py -u <user> -p <password> access`

where `<user>` is an emergency user login name you are creating, `<password>` - password for this user to log in.

You will get a file access created in the utilities folder. 
Move this access file into your instance (data1/parts/instance) folder with the following command

mv access ../../instance/

Now change your location form data1/parts/zope2/utilities to data1/bin, and restart your instance

`cd ../../../bin`

`./instance restart`

Login to ZMI with newly created emergency user login
Create usual Zope admin user and login with it to do all the necessary stuff in ZMI.

for more information see [tutorial](http://quintagroup.com/services/support/tutorials/zope-access)

Comment: You may want to actually [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34767139/edit) your answer across accordingly - the reason you saw my comment was because your answer is in a review queue (hence the [*From Review*](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10878982) link) - if five people recommend deletion (and I suspect they may), your answer will be deleted.